# Azan in loudspeakers

Tags: islamic-philosophy, adhan

I would like to know if it is allowed to recite Azan in loudspeakers. As some people who doesn't have faith in Islam say they get disturbed with Azan while they are asleep. Many non believers say they get affected by it and Islam religion is forced upon them which they don't like as they don't believe in it.